# How are these functions implemented?

Tags: python, image-processing

```py
def im2col(input_data, filter_h, filter_w, stride=1, pad=0):
    N, C, H, W = input_data.shape
    out_h = (H + 2 * pad - filter_h)//stride + 1
    out_w = (W + 2 * pad - filter_w)//stride + 1

    img = np.pad(input_data, [(0,0), (0,0), (pad, pad), (pad, pad)], 'constant')
    col = np.zeros((N, C, filter_h, filter_w, out_h, out_w))

    for y in range(filter_h):
        y_max = y + stride*out_h
        for x in range(filter_w):
            x_max = x + stride * out_w
            # why!!!!!
            col[:, :, y, x, :, :] = img[:, :, y:y_max:stride, x:x_max:stride]  

    col = col.transpose(0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3).reshape(N*out_h*out_w, -1)
    # why!!!!!
    return col


def col2im(col, input_shape, filter_h, filter_w, stride=1, pad=0):
    N, C, H, W = input_shape
    out_h = (H + 2 * pad - filter_h)//stride + 1
    out_w = (W + 2 * pad - filter_w)//stride + 1
    # why!!!!!
    col = col.reshape(N, out_h, out_w, C, filter_h, filter_w).transpose(0, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2)  

    img = np.zeros((N, C, H + 2 * pad + stride - 1, W + 2 * pad + stride - 1))
    for y in range(filter_h):
        y_max = y + stride * out_h
        for x in range(filter_w):
            x_max = x + stride * out_w
            # why!!!!!
            img[:, :, y:y_max:stride, x:x_max:stride] += col[:, :, y, x, :, :]


    return img[:, :, pad:H + pad, pad:W + pad]
```

I cannot understand the lines below the one's I've marked with the comment "# why!!!!!".
Why they are implemented like that multidimensionally?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Ask the authors of that code?!?!